# My html/javascript/css site works in IE but not in FF

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox

[www.warhawkcomputers.com/Birenbaum](http://www.warhawkcomputers.com/Birenbaum)

This site has various projects for my Computer class that I am in. A check is coming up and all programs will need to work in FF and IE.

My Bouncing Ball, Race Track, and Tanks projects under Third quarter as well as pong under Fourth Quarter work in IE when the objects need to be moved by a continuously adding variable performed in a javascript script, and it works perfectly fine in IE, but when viewed with Firefox 3, the moving objects no longer move and I have tested to find out it gets the variables but seems to only add it once and that the `document.getElementById("objectname").style.left` = "continuously adding variable" seems to not be executed despite being in a timer running every 10 milliseconds.

Also, none of my `keypress` code works in Firefox, but I believe that is because I use an outdated method of moving objects via keypress. This is largely due to my teacher's outdated methods.

Thanks for all of your guys's help.

Comment: Welcome to the world of browser non-standardization.

Comment: Would probably need to see your html/js/css.

Comment: @mrust: ...the first item in his post is a link to all that

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a 'units' to your positions:

```
document.getElementById("ball").style.left = x + 'px';
document.getElementById("ball").style.top = y + 'px';
```

That will work in FF as well now.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox does not use a global `event` object.  They pass an event object into the handler.  As a result, you need to modify your `Move` function:

```
function Move(e) {
    /* snip */
    var whichkey = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    /* ... */
```

Gerrat is absolutely correct about the other problem you asked about.

**EDIT**: this won't work with how you hooked your event handler in the body tag.  You need to remove the `onkeydown="Move()"` attribute from the body tag and add the following code at the top of `JavaScript.js`:

```
document.body.onkeydown=Move;
```

If allowed to do so by your teacher, you would be MUCH better off using jQuery or some other framework.

Comment: You should be able to accept two answers, as you're both right.  Nice completion lawnsea

Comment: Thanks Guys. I will work on this tomorrow. Sadly, my instructor is insisting I do it in JavaScript to learn to appreciate the other frameworks when we transition into them.